# Getting related entities from intersect entity D365 C#

Tags: c#, sdk, microsoft-dynamics

I've retrieved an intersect entity and the two entities related to it.

I've linked the entities to the query (to my belief).

When I run the code, all intersect entities appear, but I can't figure out how to get any data from them, even the name of the name.

Please see below code: .

```
private static EntityCollection GetOpportunityAndInstallationSiteIntersectEntity(IOrganizationService service)

        var installationSite = "csp_installationsite";
                    var opportunity = "opportunity";
                    var relationshipName = "csp_opportunity_csp_installationsite";
        
                    var relationshipQuery = new QueryExpression(installationSite)
                    {
                        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)
                    };
        
                    var linkInstallationSite = new LinkEntity(installationSite, relationshipName, "csp_installationsiteid","csp_installationsiteid" ,JoinOperator.Inner);
                    var linkOpportunity = new LinkEntity(opportunity, relationshipName, "opportunityid", "opportunityid" ,JoinOperator.Inner);
        
                    linkInstallationSite.LinkEntities.Add(linkOpportunity);
        
                    relationshipQuery.LinkEntities.Add(linkInstallationSite);
                    var RelationshipCollection = service.RetrieveMultiple(relationshipQuery);
                    Console.WriteLine("Retrieved {0} Intersect Entities", RelationshipCollection.Entities.Count);
        
        foreach (Entity IS in RelationshipCollection.Entities)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Intersect Entity:", IS["csp_name"]);
                    }
        
        return RelationshipCollection;
    


    I'd just like to know how I can get the records related to the intersect. 
    Lets call an entity A, I want to deprecate it, but it's related to Entity B in a N:N relationship.
    
    I've created a new entity, which is related to entity A in PowerAutomate.
```

I want all of Entity B to now be related to this Entity I made in PowerAutomate.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your code I could get access to the Installation Site attributes and I just modified it slightly to get the all the attributes from the opportunity.

The code below loops through the name attributes of both the Opportunity and Installation Site.

```
private static EntityCollection GetOpportunityAndInstallationSiteIntersectEntity(IOrganizationService service)
{
    var installationSite = "csp_installationsite";
    var opportunity = "opportunity";
    var relationshipName = "csp_opportunity_csp_installationsite";

    var relationshipQuery = new QueryExpression(installationSite)
    {
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)
    };

    var linkInstallationSite = relationshipQuery.AddLink(relationshipName, "csp_installationsiteid", "csp_installationsiteid", JoinOperator.Inner);
    var linkOpportunity = linkInstallationSite.AddLink(opportunity, "opportunityid", "opportunityid", JoinOperator.Inner);
    linkOpportunity.EntityAlias = "opp";
    linkOpportunity.Columns.AllColumns = true;
    var RelationshipCollection = service.RetrieveMultiple(relationshipQuery);

    foreach (Entity IS in RelationshipCollection.Entities)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Intersect Entity: {IS["csp_name"]} {((AliasedValue)IS["opp.name"]).Value}");
    }

    return RelationshipCollection;
}
```

From there you will need to associate the records to the new entity and dissociate the old one